# Consulta a URL XML

Tags: php, web-service, xml, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando pegar alguns dados de uma URL com codigo XML mas esta dando erro.
Segue o codigo

```
 <?php
$simples = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://vallesw.azurewebsites.net/api/municipiosfranqueados');

//Pega o segundo...
$segundo = $simples->NewDataSet->CarregaMunicipioFranqueados[1];
//Pega o codigo
$codigo = $segundo->{'Codigo_Municipio'};
$municipio = $segundo->Municipio;

echo "Esse é o codigo: $codigo";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Esse é o municipio: $municipio";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então Amigo, nessa primeira linha já temos um error, você está chamando a variável **$xml** que ainda não existe.

```
<?php
$simples = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://vallesw.azurewebsites.net/api/municipiosfranqueados');
```

Sobre a criação do objeto simpleXMLElement do documento xml, quando você usa o `simplexml_load_file()` ele faz a leitura do documento XML e retorna um objeto do tipo SimplexmlElement (Obs: se o XML estive mal formado ele retorna false), então não tem a necessidade de instanciar um SimpleXMLElement, como foi feito na primeira linha, bastaria fazer:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://vallesw.azurewebsites.net/api/municipiosfranqueados');
$segundo = $xml->NewDataSet->CarregaMunicipioFranqueados[1];
$codigo = $segundo->Codigo_Municipio;
$municipio = $segundo->Municipio;

echo "Esse é o codigo: $codigo";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Esse é o municipio: $municipio";
?>
```

Só que tem um detalhe, eu fiz uns teste aqui e percebi outro problema, está com  um problema no content-type do header da paginá que exibe o xml, e quando o `simplexml_load_file($url)` carregava o xml, dava um error: **`Start tag expected, '&lt;'`**, então fiz a seguinte correção:

```
<?php
$url = "http://vallesw.azurewebsites.net/api/municipiosfranqueados";
$xml = file_get_contents($url); // Pega o conteúdo da url e armazena em string
$xml = stripcslashes($xml); // remove  '\n','\r' da string
$xml = str_replace("\"", "",$xml); // remover aspas dulas do inicio e fim da string.
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); // ler a string e retorna um objeto SimpleXMLElement
$segundo  = $xml->CarregaMunicipioFranqueados[1];
$codigo   = $segundo->Codigo_Municipio;
$municipio= $segundo->Municipio;
echo "Esse é o codigo: $codigo";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Esse é o municipio: $municipio";
?>
```

Espero ter conseguido ajudar man.

Comment: Victor
Muito Obrigado era exatamente isso que eu estava tentando fazer e estava com muita dificuldade. Obrigado pela sua ajuda!