# Como exibir o resultado da leitura de um arquivo XML de maneira correta

Tags: php, json, xml

Bom dia ,

Me surgiu a necessidade de realizar a leitura de um arquivo XML disponibilizado em uma URL, no entanto , mesmo seguindo as perguntas já abertas aqui no stack como :[Consulta a URL XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199700/consulta-a-url-xml) os dados me são retornados sem nenhuma informação sendo que tenho garantia que existe conteúdo nessa URL.

Quando utilizo esse sistema de leitura:

```
      <?php
        $xml =simplexml_load_file('https://www.meusite.com.br/X/teste.xml');
      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($xml);
      echo "</pre>";   
      ?>
```

Me é retornado a estrutura sem nenhum dado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual erro estou cometendo ao exibir esse arquivo?

Comment: Blz , editei a pergunta e agora ela levanta a questão real , formatei com `<pre>`e realmente foi formatado no formato convencional no entanto não exibido nenhum conteúdo.

Comment: O xml pode estar com erro de syntax, ve isso aqui [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) pra verifica erro de syntax no xml na hora de carrega.